# NodeJS MySQL Returning Empty Array When Passing Integers To Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js, node-mysql

**SECOND EDIT**

The issue was caused by the MAX_INTEGER_VALUE which is lower then the integer value I was passing. I changed the MySQL table column to `TEXT` instead of `BIGINT` and everything is being returned correctly.

Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT**

So I just realized that the `userID` variable and the `guildID` variables are being passed using this line of code.

`mysqlModule.userCrewSearch(575783451018526744, 282997056438665217);`

However the values that are being supplied to the SQL statement turn the last two digits of the number into '00'. So instead of `575783451018526744` the value being passed into the SQL statement is `575783451018526700`.

[image: Edited Question Image]

So why is this value being changed when nothing I am doing in my code is changing these values?

**Original Post**

I'll keep this short and sweet. I'm trying to run a query using the nodejs MySQL package. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but whenever I call my function that executes my query, I'm always returned an empty array, unless I hardcode the values into the SQL query.

Heres the code:

```
// Search for the User's Crew
function userCrewSearch(guildID, userID) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) { 
            return console.log(err);
        }
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM `crew-members` WHERE `userID`=? AND `guildID`=?;";
        console.log(sql);
        connection.query(sql, [guildID, userID], function(err, results) {
            connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
            if(err) { 
                return console.log(err);
            }
            return console.log(results);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm calling this function like so: `userCrewSearch(575783451018526744, 282997056438665217);`

Both of the values I'm passing are integers. However this is what I get in my console.

[image: Broken Code]

However, here is my code with the values hardcoded into the SQL... to which the code then returns the result in the form of a RowDataPacket.

```
// Search for the User's Crew
function userCrewSearch(guildID, userID) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) { 
            return console.log(err);
        }
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM `crew-members` WHERE `userID`=282997056438665217 AND `guildID`=575783451018526744;";
        console.log(sql);
        connection.query(sql, [guildID, userID], function(err, results) {
            connection.release(); // always put connection back in pool after last query
            if(err) { 
                return console.log(err);
            }
            return console.log(results);
        });
    });
}
```

Heres the result.

[image: Working Code]

**Bonus Question:** How do I handle the RowDataPacket? Can I convert this directly into an object so I can call `results.crewID` and return just that value?

Comment: Your query has the parameters in order of `userID` first, and `guildID` second, but your function uses them in reverse order. Is that intentional?

Comment: It looks like it's truncating 16 characters, so maybe you're running into some INTEGER length restriction?

Comment: It is not, but thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: Just added a second edit. :D

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i was facing few days ago. I have solved this by converting the parameters into string.

```
function userCrewSearch(String(guildID), String(userID)) {

       //  your code here 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See Attached Screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y15ogdtgl2g7pzo/Screenshot%202019-06-10%2002.11.34.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gehramzx1wzz7y/Screenshot%202019-06-10%2002.12.27.png?dl=0

Comment: can you please remove extra space from parameters. Try this 'String(guildID), String(userID)' instead of String  (guildID), String  (userID)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding + before your numeric parameter, it converts into number,  it worked for me-

```
connection.query(sql, [+guildID, +userID], function(err, results) {
```

for your bonus questions answer, you can directly access the crewID or some other key using,

```
results[0].crewID
```

or do something like -

```
const [ result ] = results;
console.log(result.crewID)
```

Comment: This didn't work either. :/ See attached screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9o3fu8xdcw5sy9q/Screenshot%202019-06-10%2013.23.10.png?dl=0 AND https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm77802lp2on4hg/Screenshot%202019-06-10%2013.23.37.png?dl=0

Comment: try to console the guildID and  userID inside userCrewSearch(), see whether the value is coming, 

console.log(isNaN(guildID));
console.log(isNaN(userID));
check whether its coming as false or true.